# Center UIImageView inside UITableView Header

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a UIImageView to my UITableView Header and now I am trying to center is, but it won't center, it goes to the right.

```
let imageHeader = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
let header = UIView(frame : CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width : self.tableView.frame.width, height : 200))
imageHeader.image = UIImage(named: "paindown-logo.png")
imageHeader.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageHeader.center = CGPoint(x: header.bounds.midX, y: header.bounds.midY);
header.addSubview(imageHeader)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

What am I doing wrong? Why will not center?

[image]

Comment: do u have a screenshoot? Also are you using any constraints?

Comment: _When_ are you running that code? If in `viewDidLoad`, that's the problem.

Comment: it is in viewDidload

Comment: I am not using constraints

Comment: which menu you use?/

Comment: Try to debug by finding the bounds of your `UIImageView` and `UITableView` in your screen. The results might surprise you.

Comment: @user979331 which Side menu you are using? and what is width of your tableview?

Comment: Try setting the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews. It worked out for me.

Comment: I moved this code to viewWillAppear and now it works

Answer (score 0):

reload your `imageHeader view` then reload your `table view` after open menu.